# How to use Google safe browsing lookup API

Tags: google-api

I've just stumbled onto Google Safe Browsing lookup API and will admit this seems to be a bit above my head, but I still would like to learn how to use it.

I've read through the get-started documentation, but I am still confused on where to actually begin.

I've created an API key to access it, which gave me a link.

I've pasted that link into Google Chrome, and it downloaded a file, which I opened in Google Chrome on my Win 7 machine.

This is where I am stuck, where is the API?

How do I actually paste URL's into the API to see if they are malicious or not?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're still wondering about this 6 months later an API is a way of interacting with a site not through your browser. You don't need to worry about it if you're using Chrome or Firefox since the browser will do it for you.

However, you know how a website for a bar will have a small google maps box with the map of the area? The application (website) sent a `get` request to the Google Maps API. The simplest way you do this at home is with your terminal or command line. That's where you would type in the url you're trying to check.